# How can I change the "x"th value to "y"?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class IntArray {
private:
    int* m_data;
    int m_len;
public:
    IntArray(int = 0, int = 0);
    ~IntArray();
    void print(void);
    
    void set(int x, int y) {//!!!
        int temp = x

        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
};
IntArray::IntArray(int size, int init) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        m_data = nullptr;
        m_len = 0;
    }
    else {
        m_data = new int[size];
        m_len = size;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < m_len; ++idx)
            *(m_data + idx) = init;
    }
}
IntArray::~IntArray() {
    delete[]m_data;
}
void IntArray::print(void) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < m_len; ++idx)
        cout << *(m_data + idx) << ' ';
    cout << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    cout << "a1: ";
    IntArray a1{ 10, 100 };
    a1.print();
    cout << "a2: ";
    IntArray a2{ a1 };
    a2.set(3, 999);
    a2.set(9, 123);
    a2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

When I output a2, I want to output "999" at the third and "123" at the ninth and "100" at the rest. However, with the code I wrote, only "100" is printed.How should I fix it?
**Output**

> a1: 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
> a2: 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100

**Expected**

> a1: 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
> a2: 100 100 100 999 100 100 100 100 100 123

Comment: Your set function doesn't do anything. It works with three local variables. It does **not** change the state of the object or return anything, so calling set is as good as not calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. Let's look at your `set` method:

```
    void set(int x, int y) {
        int temp = x

        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
```

The above just takes in a pair of parameters, `x` and `y`. Swaps the values of these **local** variables, but then doesn't actually change anything on the instance of your IntArray class that's being invoked.  What did you expect to happen?

Here's another hint. Your `print` method enumerates over values in `m_data`. Perhaps that's a clue to what `set` should really be doing.

TLDR: your `set` method need to apply the value of `y` to m_data at an index of `x`. It should also validate that x is less than m_len as well before accessing m_data.

Comment: If there is no copy constructor, a default copy constructor will provide, and if I write "IntArray(const IntArray&copy)" above "~IntArray()", an error will occur. So how do I solve this?

Comment: @고건원 - you are asking a completely different question in the comments. Start a new question regarding copy constructors and compiler errors.